# Excel Confidence

Tags: crystal-reports, excel, vba

Just have a simple question.

Does CR11 R2 has CONFIDENCE function from Excel?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828124

If not how do I get confidential value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Crystal does not have a confidence() function.  However, you can calculate any confidence interval you want using the StdDev() and Variance() functions.

[image: http://i25.tinypic.com/59ycjo.png]

Comment: Sorry, I really don't have time to go through the statistics. However, if you look up the Confidence() function in the Excel help files, you'll find everything you need.